# How to reuse a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, return

I have the variable `total` in a function. Say that I'd like to use that variable in an if statement in another function. I can use the `return` keyword and return that variable from my first function but how would I use that variable in an if statement that would be outside that function or even in a different function?

Comment: Have you tried reading through a Python tutorial? This question is a little basic for Stack Overflow, and it's bard to answer a question when you don't have the basics of how programs are structured down. It's not a bad question, but it would be better answered by an introductory programming text.

Answer (score 2):

You could re-declare the variable with the value from the function. I don't have a lot of information, but I think this is what you mean.

```
def some_function():
    total=10
    return total
total=some_function()
print(total)
```

Comment: would i be able to use some_function() rather than assigning it to a variable and using that variable, in this case the variable total

Comment: Yeah but it would be better to use a new variable

Comment: is there are reason for that?

Comment: Well it depends on what you will use the ```total``` variable for. It's value can change in the function if you were to call it multiple times. if this answered your question please mark it as correct to keep up good practice!

Comment: either way though assigning the function to a variable just seems like extra work because that variable that the function is being assigned to will always equal to the function: `function()`  =  `varforfunction = function()`

Comment: if i understand your comment correctly, that would be the only way because of scope. You would have to call the function at some point because the function is what is making the variable and assigning it a value. You wouldn't even have a ```total``` variable without calling the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247090/discussion-between-kirill-mcquillin-and-dmkc-gamer).

Answer (score 1):

`return` the value from your first function, and then a call to that function will evaluate to that value.  You can assign the value to a variable, or pass it directly to another function.  In either case, the value doesn't need to be assigned to the same variable name in different scopes.

```
def func_a():
    total = 42
    return total

def func_b(the_answer):
    if the_answer == 42:
        print("That's the answer to the ultimate question!")

func_b(func_a())
```

Comment: would i be able to assign the returned value from my first function to a variable without calling that first function?

Comment: Where would the value come from if you don't call the function?  Nothing inside the function body (including the definition of the value) is executed until the function is called.